# Ansible - Use wildcard in amazon.aws

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

I am setting up some new HPC clusters and am having trouble putting some Ansible automation together. Basically, we have a DellEMC ECS, and I need to create a playbook to delete all versions of ALL files in a S3 bucket.

I am having issues where the 'amazon.aws.s3_bucket' module will only delete buckets if they are empty, and the 'amazon.aws.s3_object' module requires a filename. I am trying to delete all files in a bucket so it can be deleted.

This is the basic form I am using omitting a couple fields with my endpoint and creds.

```
- name: Delete an object from a bucket
  amazon.aws.s3_object:
    bucket: mybucket
    object: /my/desired/key.txt
    mode: delobj
```

I apologize if this is a dumb question, I am very new to Ansible.

Comment: It's not a dumb question, but your mention of "all versions" means you have to separately list the *versions* of those keys. Since I don't readily see an ansible module for doing that, I believe you'll have to use `command:` [`aws s3api list-object-versions`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/list-object-versions.html) along with `register: the_s3api_output` to deal with that situation. Another approach is to use lifecycle policies to delete the bucket over time, depending on how many objects x versions there are